# How to push actions to already defined before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am writing a redmine plugin and need to add some actions to `before_filter` that is already defined in redmine's 'IssuesController'

For example,

**issues_controller.rb**

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :find_issue, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
   before_filter :find_issues, :only => [:bulk_edit, :bulk_update, :destroy]
   before_filter :find_project, :only => [:new, :create, :update_form]
   before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index]
end
```

I want to add more actions to filters `find_issue` and `find_project`

So, in my plugin i'm gonna write a module and include it in `IssuesController`

**issues_controller_patch.rb**

```
  module IssuesControllerPatch
    def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
      base.class_eval do
        before_filter :find_issue, :only => [:new_action1, :new_action2]
        before_filter :find_project, :only => [:new_action1, :new_action2]
        #prepend_before_filter :find_issue, :only => [:new_action1, :new_action2]
        #prepend_before_filter :find_project, :only => [:new_action1, :new_action2]
      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  unless IssuesController.included_modules.include?(IssuesControllerPatch)
    IssuesController.send(:include, IssuesControllerPatch)
  end
```

This is not working for me, because it's putting it on the bottom of filters chain and `authorize` action is executed and authorization is because authorization depends on `project`.

I also tried to use `prepend_before_filter` and it's also not working because it's putting it on the top of filters chain, even before the `user` loads from session.

So, how can I update action list for filters defined in `IssuesController`?

**Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3, Redmine 2.6**

Comment: how about writing out `find_issue` and `find_project` containing only  `re-direct_to ....` statements, in the `IssuesControllerPatch` module itself.

Comment: try `prepend_before_action [ :find_issue, :find_project ]` after defining those actions

Comment: I meant you shell define before_actions, and then additinally put then into top of list with `prepend_before_action`. Did you do with such way?

Comment: Well, can put it on the top of `filters` list because then these filters will be called first and it is not intended.